# compare seconds in timestamp in oracle with join operation

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Can any one help me to write a query in oracle to get details like this
**(I am joining two tables with user and loc)**

```
table1.id | table1.type | table2.tag  | table2.status|
------------------------------------------------------
  1       |    type1    |     tag1    |     status1    
  1       |    type1    |     tag2    |     status2
```

from two tables

**table1**

```
id |  user   |    loc    |      timestamp         |   type
------------------------------------------------------------
1  |   user1 |     loc1  |    12-12-2014 12:12:23 |   type1    
2  |   user1 |     loc1  |    12-12-2014 12:10:24 |   type2
```

**table2**

```
user   |    loc  |      timestamp          |   tag    |  status
---------------------------------------------------------------------
user1  |    loc1 |    12-12-2014 12:12:23  |   tag1   |  status1      
user1  |    loc1 |    12-12-2014 12:12:26  |   tag2   |  status2    
user2  |    loc1 |    12-12-2014 12:12:26  |   tag3   |  status1
```

My need is to get details from two tables..my request include

->datepart (for eg 12-12-2014) to search whether this date matches with timestamp in table1
.if it matches get that details,so we get some timestamps.then compare these timestamps with  table2 timestamp.if these timestamp matches with between table2.timestamp+20seconds  and table1.timestamp.get the two tables merged result..

Comment: Look at the syntax for [INTERVAL literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm). It might prove useful for your assignment. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Should (not) tag3 also be listed in the output with NULL values for table1.id and table1.type?

Comment: that will not list.beacause its username is different.i am joining tables.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you look for such a clause in your JOIN or WHERE condition:

```
table2.TIMESTAMP BETWEEN table1.TIMESTAMP AND table1.TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '20' SECOND
```